# Isolate specific number from 13-character number using formula field

Tags: formula, administration, formula-field

We're receiving a 13-character number from SAP. The number will start with 0's until the actual number starts. The last 3 digits will always be 0 and correspond to the decimals.

For example, the number 3 would look like this: 0000000003000. The number 12345 would look like this: 0000012345000.

We have to isolate only the number, without any 0's that come before or after it. I have already filtered out the decimals (3 last 0's), but I'm struggling with filtering out the first x-amount using a formula field.

Any tips are most welcome to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
VALUE(LEFT(SAPid__c, 10));
```

So we are using Left function to strip last 3 digit from 13 characters.

Then we are converting the remaining string into integer using VALUE function.